# How to run Sitecore in Live Mode?

Tags: configuration

I need to run my front-end website by pointing to master database, temporarily.

What settings should I change to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The settings are: `database=master`, `filterItems=true` and `enableWorflow=true`.

There is an example patch file included in `App_Config/Include` named `LiveMode.config.example`.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="filterItems">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableWorkflow">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Match the site name ('website' in this example') to the corresponding site name to enable Live Mode for. You can rename the included `LiveMode.config.example` file to `LiveMode.config` to enable the patch or make the changes to the site node definition for your local development environment.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @bmyers is the recommended solution, but it is also possible to update the `web` connectionstring and point it directly to the master database:

`<add name="web" connectionString="user id=sa;password=Password01;Data Source=.;Database=MySiteSitecore_Master"/>`

The above is useful in CI type environments when you need to quickly change variables at deploy time for testing purposes.

Comment: Isn't this quite dangerous? If someone decides to publish the entire site while web is pointing to master, unpublished content and item versions could be deleted.