# Sitecore AutoPublish only for one Publishing target

Tags: publishing, publishing-targets

We have 2 publishing targets say X and Y. When someone makes a change in current DB, I need the changes to be automatically published to X but not Y.

And I don't want to show X in the Publish Item/Site Panel when I manually publish.

Comment: You can add Sitecore event handler which will be executed on every item created/saved/moved/deleted/etc event and publish the item into the database choose. You would need to consider things like workflows, checking if the current version is the latest version of the item and maybe other things. So it's really hard to give you a precise answer without knowing exact requirements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unclear and abandoned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

What if you keep Y as usual, linked to web database, and set up x in live mode, linked to master database as described [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/340/151)
This way you will only see Y in the publish option, and you don't have to publish to X at all.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply .but that doesn't help me in my situation as we the DB X is located in Different region.

Comment: Have you considered doing a synchronisation at database level? Publishing everything may be a lot of events to handle and a pain if you have workflows...